# Missing base class in ATL COM+ Component class declaration generated by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, com, atl

I am using Visual Studio "Add Class" wizard to add an ATL Com+ 1.0 Component, named CTestClass; I checked the checkbox of the `SupportErrorInfo`. See the screenshot. [image]

However, in the auto-generated TestClass.h file, the class `ISupportErrorInfo` is not listed as a base class.

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CTestClass :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
                           // <-- missing "ISupportErrorInfo" although it is checked on the settings (screenshot);
    public IObjectControl, // <-- checked on the settings (screenshot)
    public IObjectConstruct, // <-- checked on the settings (screenshot)
    public CComCoClass<CTestClass, &CLSID_TestClass>,
    public IDispatchImpl<ITestClass, &IID_ITestClass, &LIBID_gdCloudPaymentsLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>
{...}
```

I am using VisualStudio Premium 2013 Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5.

What did I miss or anything wrong in Visual Studio?

Comment: It may be a bug as it seems to be working with Visual Studio 2022. Visual Studio 2013 mainstream support has ended 4 years ago (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2013) so there's very little chance this may be fixed, if even considered